# How do I pass a dynamic page :id to $http.get url in Vue.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, vue.js

I have have view router set up:

```
router.map({
    '/tracks/:id': {
        component: SingleTrack
    }
})
```

And this is my component (which works with a hard coded URL):

```
var SingleTrack = Vue.component('track', {

    template: '#track-template',

    data: function() {
        return {
            track: ''
        }
    },

    ready: function() {
        this.$http.get('//api.trax.dev/tracks/1', function (data) {
            this.$set('track', data.track)
        })
    }
});
```

How do I pass the url/:id to the end of the `$http.get` string so i can grab the correct data dynamically when that route in loaded, something like:

```
ready: function(id) {
    this.$http.get('//api.trax.dev/tracks/' + id, function (data) {
        this.$set('track', data.track)
    })
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should be able to get the route parameter from the component `$route` property :

```
var itemId = this.$route.params.id;
this.$http.get('//api.trax.dev/tracks/' + itemId, function (data) {
    this.$set('track', data.track)
})
```

See more details in [vue.js router documentation](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/dynamic-matching.html)

Comment: Thanks, that has worked - I did look through the doc's but now I see the context from your answer - Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

For Best Practises:

index.js(router)

```
{
    path: '/tracks/:id',
    name: 'SingleTrack',
    component: SingleTrack,
    props: (route) => {
        const id = Number.parseInt(route.params.id);
        return { id }
      },
  }
```

SingleTrack.vue

```
props: {
 id: {
  type: Number,
  required: true,
 },
},

mounted(){
 this.$http.get('//api.trax.dev/tracks/' +this.id, function (data) {
    this.$set('track', data.track)
 })
}
```